# pyodbc cursor execute with or without params

Tags: python, pyodbc

how can I execute a query without doing like this specially if a parameters wasn't provided?

```
def query_fetch(self, sql_query, params=None, fetchall=True, *args):
    with self.cursor.execute(sql_query) if params is None else self.cursor.execute(sql_query, params):
        row = self.cursor.fetchall() if fetchall else self.cursor.fetchone()
        r = [d for d in row]
    return r
```

Comment: What do you mean "without doing like this"? Is it related to the if else condition?

Comment: yes, because I'm not really sure how I can make the execute ignore params if it's none. It feels like doing it by a conditional statement is so unlikely

Comment: An alternative is to use [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) in Pandas

Answer (score 0):

What you are already doing seems perfectly reasonable. If the SQL command text contains no parameter placeholders then you must call the `.execute` method with just a single string argument. If the SQL command text contains parameter placeholders then you must call the `.execute` method with the same number of parameter values following the initial string (command text) argument.